# Regex Replacement

Tags: regex, match

I have a string:

`users/554983490\/Another+Test+/Question????\/+dhjkfsdf/`

How would i write a RegExp that would match all of the forward slashes NOT preceded by a back slash?

**EDIT:** Is there a way to do it without using a negative lookbehinds?

Comment: Which language are you using for your RegExp? There are many flavors...

Comment: You can't do that reliably, even with lookbehinds.  But if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regular expressions support [negative lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<!\\)\//
```

Otherwise, you will **need to match the character before the `/` as well**:

```
/(^|[^\\])\//
```

This matches either the start of a string (`^`), or (`|`) anything other than a `\` (`[^\\]`) as capture group #1 `()`.  Then it matches the literal `/` after.  Whatever character was before the `/` will be stored in the capture group `$1` so you can put it back in if you are doing a replace....

Example (JavaScript):

```
'st/ri\\/ng'.replace(/(^|[^\\])\//, "$1\\/");
// returns "st\/ri\/ng"
```

Comment: The negative lookbehind doesn't include it... The second match will, but if you don't support negative lookbehinds, its your only option...  You could do something like `'st/ri\\/ng'.replace(/(^|[^\\])\//, "$1\\/");` in javascript for instance to add the backslash to any `/` that don't already have it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
/(?<!\\)\//
```

This is called a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

I used / as the delimiters

```
(?<!   <-- Start of the negative lookbehind (means that it should be preceded by the following pattern)
  \\     <--  The \ character (escaped)
)      <-- End of the negative lookbehind
\/     <-- The / character (escaped)
```